# Z-Index unfocus text field

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: z-index topography]

I'm having an issue with getting my search box to unfocus. I want it to not be focused when anything is clicked, but especially the background (div.bb). The elements above background are position:fixed, but I've tried changing them to absolute and playing with the z-index with no success. Is there another way to fix this?

EDIT: the app is here http://acsoundstudio.com/bb/bbtest/

Comment: call the `.blur()` method to make it unfocused.

Comment: so something like? 

`$('div.bb').on('click', function () {
    .blur(#searchbox);
});`

Comment: something like this `$(document).on('click', function(e) { if (e.target !== $('#search')[0]) $('#search').blur();});`

Comment: niiice :) That works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Answering so this question doesn't appear to be unanswered -- it was answered in the comments of the question by [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king), so I'm just copying that content)*

Call the `.blur()` method to make it unfocused, something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e)
{
    if (e.target !== $('#search')[0])
        $('#search').blur();
});
```